# Initiating transfer between two servers via terminal

Tags: command-line-interface

I have a very large file on a different company's server (not the company I work for, just a company we work with). I have FTP credentials to login and download/upload files from them. I need to get this very large file onto our website's (the company I work for) live server.

What I'd like to avoid is the step of downloading the file to my laptop, then uploading the file to our server. I'd like a command line option that can "skip the middle man" so to speak.

Unfortunately at this point my command line knowledge is passable at best, and is something I need to work on. I'm afraid at times it prevents me from looking for or asking the right questions, which may be the case here if this question is already answered, but I couldn't find a way to frame it using Google searches to get an answer I understand.

I had a coworker point me to this article:

http://blogs.reliablepenguin.com/2009/08/11/ftps-with-lftp

However, the article doesn't explain what is happening very clearly, and I don't feel like it fully addresses what I'm trying to do, or may imply a certain level of command line understanding that I don't have. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up scp commands for a remote to remote copy

You need admin access and the passwords to both

Try this: http://www.lifelinux.com/scp-command-remote-file-copy/